# Authorize.net Profiles XML error?

Tags: xml, authorize.net, profiles

This is for Customer Profiles. I want to start by saying I'm not using XML at all, but Authorize is returning a E00003 XML parse error.

```
$controller = new AnetController\CreateCustomerProfileController($request);
$response = $controller -> executeWithApiResponse(\net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::PRODUCTION); 
        $rsp = $response -> getMessages() -> getMessage()[0] -> getCode();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it said anything about XML, but the issue was that a variable was not being properly loaded into a CreditCardType. Again, why they would tell me that it was an XML error and not a missing fields error is beyond me.